# How to remove border and change background-color in top left cell of table?

Tags: html, css

I am having a trouble with changing a top left corner cell of a table.
I have this table:

```html
<table>
 <caption>zľavové hodiny</caption>
 <tr>
  <th>zač./deň</th><th>pondelok</th><th>utorok</th><th>streda</th><th>štvrtok</th><th>piatok</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>10:00</th>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td colspan="3">práčky, sušičky (-20%)</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>12:00</th>
  <td colspan="2">mikrovlnné rúry (-25%)</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>vysávače (-30%)</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

and I have to change the background-color in top left corner cell of table. It should have background-color #CCCCCC  and shouldn't have border 5px on right side (only 1px as other sides). Everything else should remain as it is now. Any ideas what to do?

This is my CSS code:

```css
table { 
border: 5px double #999;
background-color: white;
border-spacing: 5px 1em;
empty-cells: hide;
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
}

table th, table td { 
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 0.5em;
border-collapse: collapse; 
 }
 
table tr:nth-child(1) { 
background-color: gold;
}

table th:nth-child(2) { 
border-bottom-width: 5px;
}

table th:nth-child(3) { 
border-bottom-width: 5px;
}


table th:nth-child(4) { 
border-bottom-width: 5px;
}

table th:nth-child(5) { 
border-bottom-width: 5px;
}

table th:nth-child(6) { 
border-bottom-width: 5px;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: orangered;
}
 
table tr:nth-child(1) { 
background-color: gold;
}

tr th:nth-child(1) { 
background-color: plum;
border-right-width: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tr:first-child th:first-child` selector to get/reach top-left cell.

```css
table { 
border: 5px double #999;
background-color: white;
border-spacing: 5px 1em;
empty-cells: hide;
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
}

table th, table td { 
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 0.5em;
border-collapse: collapse; 
 }
 
table tr:nth-child(1) { 
background-color: gold;
}

table th:nth-child(2) { 
border-bottom-width: 5px;
}

table th:nth-child(3) { 
border-bottom-width: 5px;
}


table th:nth-child(4) { 
border-bottom-width: 5px;
}

table th:nth-child(5) { 
border-bottom-width: 5px;
}

table th:nth-child(6) { 
border-bottom-width: 5px;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: orangered;
}
 
table tr:nth-child(1) { 
background-color: gold;
}

tr:first-child th:first-child { 
background-color: #CCCCCC;
/* add what you want */
}
```

```html
<table>
 <caption>zľavové hodiny</caption>
 <tr>
  <th>zač./deň</th><th>pondelok</th><th>utorok</th><th>streda</th><th>štvrtok</th><th>piatok</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>10:00</th>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td colspan="3">práčky, sušičky (-20%)</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>12:00</th>
  <td colspan="2">mikrovlnné rúry (-25%)</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>vysávače (-30%)</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class (blank) to the th and define (border: none; background-color:#fff !important;) in the css

```css
table { 
border: 5px double #999;
background-color: white;
border-spacing: 5px 1em;
empty-cells: hide;
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
}

table th, table td { 
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 0.5em;
border-collapse: collapse; 
 }
 
table tr:nth-child(1) { 
background-color: gold;
}

table th:nth-child(2) { 
border-bottom-width: 5px;
}

table th:nth-child(3) { 
border-bottom-width: 5px;
}


table th:nth-child(4) { 
border-bottom-width: 5px;
}

table th:nth-child(5) { 
border-bottom-width: 5px;
}

table th:nth-child(6) { 
border-bottom-width: 5px;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: orangered;
}
 
table tr:nth-child(1) { 
background-color: gold;
}

tr th:nth-child(1) { 
background-color: plum;
border-right-width: 5px;
}

.blank
{
border:none;
background-color:#fff !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <caption>zľavové hodiny</caption>
 <tr>
  <th class="blank">zač./deň</th><th>pondelok</th><th>utorok</th><th>streda</th><th>štvrtok</th><th>piatok</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>10:00</th>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td colspan="3">práčky, sušičky (-20%)</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>12:00</th>
  <td colspan="2">mikrovlnné rúry (-25%)</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>vysávače (-30%)</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your css you could do the following:

```
table  tr:nth-child(1) th:nth-child(1){
background:#CCC;
border:1px 5px 1px 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #the color;
}
```

Hope it helps.